# Handling dynamic number of textboxes in python flask server

Tags: python, forms, flask

What are some common ways to handle a HTML form data which can contain a dynamic number of textboxes.

I have a Python flask server which serves some HTML templates. It also handles form data post'ed to it. One form has dynamic number of categories.

I have been using this

```
while True:
  index = index + 1
  if 'text_box' + str(index) in request.form:
     #use that text box' value
  break
```

which doesn't look like the right thing to do at all.

Answer (score 0):

Give all the boxes the same name (`name="category"`). Then use

```
all_categories = request.form.getlist("category")
```